# Find $x_1$ and $x_2$ of the equation:

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, analysis

Without solving the equation

$$3x^2 - x-7=0$$

Find:

$$ \begin{array}{cl}
\mathrm{a)} & x_1^3 + x_2^3 \\
\mathrm{b)} & x_1^3 x_2^3 \\
\mathrm{c)} & 4 x_1^3 + 3 x_1^2 x_2 + 3 x_1 x_2^2 + 4 x_2^3
 \end{array} $$

I have the answers but I don't know the way. My solutions are:
a) $(\frac{4}{3})^3$, b) $-(\frac{7}{3})^3$, c) $\frac{193}{27}$.

I tried to use Vieta's Formulas...

Comment: I've formatted your post with MathJax to make it easier to read. You can click "edit" to see how it's done.

Comment: Check this : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

For $ a)$

Let $ x_1 $ and $ x_2 $ be the roots of the equation
$$ax^2+bx+c=3x^2-x-7=0$$

we know that
$$x_1+x_2=\frac{-b}{a}=\frac 13$$
and
$$x_1.x_2=\frac ca=\frac{-7}{3}$$

But
$$(x_1+x_2)^3=$$
$$x_1^3+x_2^3+3x_1x_2(x_1+x_2)$$

So
$$x_1^3+x_2^3=(\frac 13)^3-3.\frac{-7}{3}.\frac 13$$